# Why is Spatialite showing dates in MM-DD-YYYY format?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, sqlite

I have a table with a dates column that is formatted in MM-DD-YYYY format, as shown in SQL SELECT statements.  I'm using Qspatilite (QGIS 1.8) and Spatialite GUI.

When I ORDER BY the date column it sorts by MM, then by DD, then finally by YYYY.
In other words, I get rows like this:

> 01/04/2004
>   01/24/1987
>   02/07/1994
>   03/17/1982
>   03/27/2009
>   ...
>   12/29/1997

I understand that SQLITE doesn't enforce data types.  Is there an easy way to convert the format to YYYYMMDD (so that I can sort by date) or do I need to manually parse the date myself?

Answer (score 8):

In SQLite, and thus also in SpatiaLite, there's no date type per se. See [Datatypes In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

When a string column is saved in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" then you can apply some date functions to it, such as `strftime()` to get the date formatted in other ways. However, if you've saved your dates in any other way, they are NOT recognized as dates.

What I would do is create a new date column and insert reformatted date strings into this column from the MM/DD/YYYY strings "correctly" for SQLite. Then sorting will work properly.

So (assuming you have a primary key column `id` and your current dates column is `dates`):

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table> ADD COLUMN new_dates date;
UPDATE <your_table> SET new_dates = 
SELECT SUBSTR(t.dates, 7) || SUBSTR(t.dates, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(t.dates, 4,2)
FROM <your_table> AS t
WHERE t.id = <your_table>.id;
```

Now, `ORDER BY new_dates` should work.